# how to write text (name) for the plot (figure)

Tags: plotting, text

I have a density plot and I need to put a name (Fig 1) below the figure.

```
    data1 = {{0.025`, 
0.075`, -11.400214920233049`}, {0.025500000000000002`, 
0.075`, -11.963992707513128`}, {0.026000000000000002`, 
0.075`, -12.741850703267362`}, {0.026500000000000003`, 
0.075`, -13.941305724894162`}, {0.027000000000000003`, 
0.075`, -15.178221279983168`}, {0.0275`, 
0.075`, -13.749504372889065`}, {0.028000000000000004`, 
0.075`, -12.609957855609531`}, {0.0285`, 
0.075`, -11.857187071700594`}, {0.028999999999999998`, 
0.075`, -11.303034487911573`}, {0.029500000000000002`, 
0.075`, -10.865631132456825`}, {0.03`, 
0.075`, -10.504475410396356`}, {0.025`, 
0.0755`, -11.377275773877606`}, {0.025500000000000002`, 
0.0755`, -11.938205266072528`}, {0.026000000000000002`, 
0.0755`, -12.715416916277317`}, {0.026500000000000003`, 
0.0755`, -13.946277129967559`}, {0.027000000000000003`, 
0.0755`, -15.56393423875837`}, {0.0275`, 
0.0755`, -13.905524560704707`}, {0.028000000000000004`, 
0.0755`, -12.678646501994098`}, {0.0285`, 
0.0755`, -11.898069035777292`}, {0.028999999999999998`, 
0.0755`, -11.331086872884903`}};

p= ListDensityPlot[data1, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 13}, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["CMYKColors"]]
```

I found this using Grid and I tried below, but it doesn't work:

```
text = Text[(Fig 1)];
   Grid[{{ListDensityPlot[data1, 
PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13}], 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 13}, 
ColorFunction -> ColorData["CMYKColors"]]}, {Style[text, 
FontSize -> Scaled[0.005], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}}, 
 ItemSize -> Scaled[0.45]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a label below by:

```
Labeled[p, "Fig 1", Bottom]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped. But, do you have any idea how I can move the name a little lower?

Comment: `Labeled[p, "\n Fig 1"]`